# Animation seems to resume after cancelAnimationFrame is called

Tags: javascript, loops, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I am teaching myself to code and have written a small mouse accuracy game. For the sake of testing purposes, when the user's score (accurate clicks on the shrinking boxes) gets to 3, they win (go to a win screen). If 2 boxes disappear, then the user loses (goes to a lose screen).

[Here is my game on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/roadrunnersf/0e924wdf/8/)

I am using

```
requestframeref = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

...to animate a HTML5 canvas. I am using

```
cancelAnimationFrame(requestframeref);
```

...to stop the animation, at which point the code should take the player to a win/lose screen. I am encountering a bug where the win screen works fine, but after a few seconds the lose screen disappears and is replaced by the game. The amount of time that the lose screen appears for is roughly the same as the amount of time it takes for one of the squares/targets to shrink away, so I imagine that at some point the trgt.reset and trgt.draw methods within the draw function methods are being called again, but I cannot work out why.

I have read every SO question featuring requestAnimationFrame and many more online resources and still cannot seem to get to the bottom of this - as far as I can see I am using cancelAnimationFrame the same way in both my trgt.hit method and my draw() function.

Many thanks in advance. If there is anything I can do to make this a better/clearer question then please let me know.

Comment: A link to a Fiddle is find but you should also create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version on SO to help others reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a pretty simple one: you're calling `draw` again even after the player loses the game.

```
if (disses == dissesMax) {
  cancelAnimationFrame(requestframeref);
  scene_lose();
}
```

Should be replaced with

```
if (disses == dissesMax) {
  cancelAnimationFrame(requestframeref);
  return scene_lose();
}
```

The problem is shortly after `if ( dissess == dissesMax ) { .. }` you're calling `requestframeref = requestAnimationFrame(draw); //add movement` which will restart the game.

Adding `return` to the `if` satement ensures that if the lose condition is met you'll never re-call `draw` with the playing game state.

Comment: Thanks! Is that code best placed where it is (it works fine now) or within the trgt.diss method?

Comment: @askingaq it wouldn't work in `trgt.diss()` unless you add your lose logic in the func. and return a value indicating loss. But you would still need to check for that in `draw` and skip re-calling `requestframeref = requestAnimationFrame(draw);` anyways.

Comment: So why does the  'cancelAnimationFrame(requestframeref);..... scene_win();' work inside trgt.hit (which it seems to) when it does not work within trgt.diss?

Comment: In my opinion: You should probably move your game state logic outside of your targets to begin with. Within target you should only handle did hit, did miss, and shrink. You shouldn't be invoking winning/losing from the target object(s).